# ManytoManyField save and calculate

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I just started self learning Python and Django as a hobby recently, and have been trying to self develop a project which helps me in my construction business. I have developed certain functions in my project which give me the result I want, but is not the most ideal in terms of coding practises. However, I am just learning from scratch and modifying my code as I learn.

However, now I am stuck (maybe because my basic concept is only not correct?). Require help on how to proceed.

So here is my `models.py`

```
class FootingQuantity(models.Model):
   member_name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
   --more fields hidden--
   x_axis = models.FloatField()
   y_axis = models.FloatField()

class BeamQuantity(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(FootingQuantity)
    length = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    breadth = models.FloatField()
    height = models.FloatField()
    -- more fields --

    @property
    def length_of_beam(self):
        yy = self.location.all().values_list('y_axis', flat=True)
        xx = self.location.all().values_list('x_axis', flat=True)
        ylist = list(yy)
        xlist = list(xx)
        return abs(ylist[1] - ylist[0] + xlist[1] - xlist[0])

    @property
    def total_concrete_quantity(self):
        return float(self.length) * float(self.breadth) * float(self.width)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.length = self.length_of_beam
       self.total_quantity = self.total_concrete_quantity
       super(BeamQuantity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __float__(self):
    return self.length, self.total_quantity
```

I want my model to accept ManytoManyRelation of 2 Footings selected and then calculate the length. The length will then multiply with height and width to give me the total quantity (There are other calculations as well but I am guessing they are all just crashing due to not getting length).

Currently, when I fill the Form or try to fill in details through the admin page and click on Save, I get a ValueError

> ValueError - "<BeamQuantity: B5>" needs to have a value for field "id"
> before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I think the ManytoManyField needs to save and then the calculation needs to run. Currently both are trying to occur simultaneously and hence the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you need to create your BeamQuantity instance first, before calculating the length of beans. Leave those fields empty for a second.

To do that, I recommend you to let all the fields that require the many to many relationship to have a value, with `blank=True` and `null=True`.

So, I would rewrite the save method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id: # it means the object was already created, so has an id.
        self.length = self.length_of_beam
        self.total_quantity = self.total_concrete_quantity
        super(BeamQuantity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then when you want to create a BeanQuantity, do:

```
bean_quantity = BeanQuantity.objects.create(**fields_you_want_here)
bean_quantity.save()
```

The second line will run the code in the save method, because now the object has an id.

Comment: Tried that already, does not seem to have any effect. The error persists unfortunately.

Comment: I want the calculations which are mentioned in def length_of_beam(self): to be carried out simultaneously when I save. So that I have a float for my length which is not a default value.

Comment: It is probably persisting because you are using the `@property` decorator on the methods to calculate the length, so everytime Django tries to create a BeamQuantity instance, it runs that method even if you don't call it, this happens because if you use `@property`, django will look at it as a field. So do what I said up there and remove the property decorator, create a field for legth_of_beam and for total_concrete_quantity, and after you beanquantity has an id, calculate what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was doing all my calculations in my models.py which I have now transferred to views.py. Everything works fine now. Thanks a lot, solved.

Comment: No problem, dont forget to mark my answer as the correct one so we can help others with the same problem in the future!

Comment: Hi, I removed the @property decorator, and moved all my code to views.py.. I also removed the save function all together. Now when what should I do if I want to show the template, where the calculation is done and value received in views.py. Now I want a table in my Html which will show a list of all the BeamQuantity models with columns Member Name, Breadth, Height, Length and Total Quantity.. (Length and Total Quantity are now calculated in views.py and not saved in models.py)